# XSLT - Rename and move elements to a new node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML input file:

```
<home>
    <folders>
        <folder uuid="uuid1">
            <name>folder1</name>
            <member ref="refA" />
            <member ref="refB" />
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="uuid2">
            <name>folder2</name>
            <member ref="refC" />
            <member ref="refD" />
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="uuid3">
            <name>folder3</name>
            <member ref="refE" />
            <member ref="refF" />
        </folder>
    </folders>
</home>
```

And I would have the following tree:

```
<home>
    <folders>
        <folder uuid="uuid1">
            <name>folder1</name>
            <refNews>
                <refNew ref="refA" />
                <refNew ref="refB" />
            </refNews>
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="uuid2">
            <name>folder2</name>
            <refNews>
                <refNew ref="refC" />
                <refNew ref="refD" />
            </refNews>
        </folder>
        <folder uuid="uuid3">
            <name>folder3</name>
            <refNews>
                <refNew ref="refE" />
                <refNew ref="refF" />
            </refNews>
        </folder>
    </folders>
</home>
```

To resume :

- "member" elements become "refNew"
- All "refNew" elements are contained within a new node "refNews"

I try several XSLT templates but I can't rename and move in the same XSLT file :-(

I need your help, please.

Regards,
Zido

Comment: we expect you to show your effort to get help, we usually don't write something from start. Please show an xslt that you tried and describe the difference from your desired output - and before I forget, please do it by editing the question, don't add this information in the comments here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always better to see what you have so far and help fix where it's going wrong, but this is actually quite easy. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::member)]"/>
    <refNews>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="member"/>
    </refNews>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="member">
  <refNew>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </refNew>
</xsl:template>
```

If you don't want a `refNews` element if there aren't any `member`s, you can just wrap the `refNews` element in `<xsl:if test="member"/>`, or better yet, have the first template to match `folder[member]`.

This assumes you also have the identity template defined.

Comment: Thanks Flynn, it works perfectly. I understand my mistake: to match "member", I was looking for refNews nodes but in the second template (match="member"), refNews is unknown!